# Are there any normal and Toeplitz matrices which are not circulant?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, toeplitz-matrices, circulant-matrices

The way I understand it currently, an Euler diagram can be made of normal, circulant, and Toeplitz matrices which looks like this:

[image]
My question: is $\left( \text{Normal} \, \cap \, \text{Toeplitz} \right) - \text{Circulant} = Ø$?

Comment: Thanks @tinlyx I'm new so I couldn't do an inline image.